# Lighttpd reverse-proxy setup for Rstudio server

Tags: lighttpd, rstudio

I'm trying to set up the reverse-proxy for Rstudio as suggested here:

http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/running_with_proxy

But I'm using Lighttpd, and I can't figure out how to rewrite the url request and then proxy it.

Specifically, I'm trying to get it so that if I type in 4.4.4.4(or whatever)/rstudio it proxies it to localhost:8787 (the rstudio server:port) and I'm on my way.

Basically, I'm stuck at this:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "/rstudio" {
# url.rewrite-once = ( "/rstudio" => "" )
    proxy.server  = (
        "" => ( (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => "8787"
        ) )
    )
}
```

Lighttpd says you can't url.rewrite from within a $HTTP["url"] conditional, so I don't know how to get past this (anyone know why this is?).  Without the url.rewrite, the proxy works, except it seems that it is forwarding it to localhost:8787/rstudio, which causes Rstudio to give an error since that is not an existing folder.

I need to figure out how to get rid of that /rstudio that gets forwarded along to the proxy.  I just want it to go from 4.4.4.4/rstudio to localhost:8787

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try set your url rewrite globally. See [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/135770/rewrite-url-before-passing-to-proxy-lighttpd) answer. I hope it will be usefull.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That looks like it will solve my problem (or at least set me on the right track).  I'll give it a shot next chance I get and post back.